# Authorization Failure - Invalid credentials were provided in opentok

Tags: ios, opentok

hello friends  i am right now making chat application using opentok

Authorization Failure - Invalid credentials were provided.
i am getting this error
 i am getting session id and getting token starting from T1==

what to do?